# Regex for returning all possible sequential word groupings

Tags: php, regex

For the given string "the fox jumped over the rabbit" the following string are considered sequential word groupings

the fox jumped over the rabbit,
the fox jumped over the,
the fox jumped over,
the fox jumped,
the fox,
fox jumped over the rabbit,
fox jumped over the,
fox jumped over,
fox jumped,
jumped over the rabbit,
umped over the,
jumped over,
over the rabbit,
over the,
the rabbit

Can anyone suggest or provide a suitable regex. I have tried several variations of

```
\b\w*\b\s+(\b\w*+\b\s?
```

but I can't seem to get an expression which returns the complete expected result set.

Regards,
SOliver.

Comment: Perhaps a `Regex` isn't the best option here.

Comment: this isn't what a regex is for. generally once a regex has found a match in a string, it continues to match everything afterwards. it wouldn't match the same word over and over.

Comment: I thought it might be a lazy man's, thanks for the timely responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codepad: http://codepad.org/E4rywXD8

```
$s = "the fox jumped over the rabbit";
$s = split(' ', $s);
$result = array();
foreach ($s as $key => $word)
{
    $r = array();
    for ($i = $key; $i < count($s); $i++)
    {
        $r[] = $s[$i];
        if(count($r) > 1) $result[] = implode(' ', $r);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is beautiful, thanks. I can't remember why I asked the question but I'm glad I did.

Comment: Thanks, that is nice of you to say! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Ruby script to do it with regexes using standard in/out:

```
@map = {}
def scan(str)
    if(str && str=~/\w+\s\w+/)
        @map[str] = nil
        scan(str.sub(/\s?\w+$/,""))
        scan(str.sub(/^\w+\s?/,""))
    end
end
scan(gets)
puts @map
```